# Azure IotHub download edge device configuration

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am looking for an endpoint in Azure IotHub to download the full configuration of an edge device.

```
{
    "modulesContent": {
      "$edgeAgent": {
        "properties.desired": {
          "modules": {...
          "runtime": {...
          "schemaVersion": "1.0",
          "systemModules": {
            "edgeAgent": {...
            "edgeHub": {...
        }
      },
      "$edgeHub": {
        "properties.desired": {...
      }
    }
  }
```

There is an [endpoint to apply the configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/configuration/applyonedgedevice), but I just cannot find a way to access the configuration with code :-)

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to query the local configuration is:

```
az iot hub module-twin show -n <name-of-your-hub> -d <edge-device-name> -m '$edgeAgent'
```

If you want to query a current status you can add `--query 'properties.reported.modules'`

In addition when you have the module ids you can query the module twin as well using:

```
az iot hub module-twin show --hub-name <name-of-your-hub> --device-id <edge-device-name> --module-id <module-name>
```

Hopefully it answers your question